# How to fix the previous and next button in angular

Tags: angular

How do I fix the previous and next button? After clicking next, it doesn't change it. When you click again the next button, it will only change once.

here's the code
***list.component.html***

```html
<div class="calendar">
    <span [textContent]="weekRange"></span>
</div>
<div nz-col nzXs="6"  nzSm="6"  nzMd="6"  nzXl="5"  nzXXl="6">
    <fa-icon [icon]='icons.faArrowCircleLeft' class="btn-prev" (click)="calAction('previous')"></fa-icon>
</div>
<div nz-col nzXs="12" nzSm="12" nzMd="12" nzXl="13" nzXXl="12">
    <button nz-button class="btn-today" nzGhost (click)="calAction('today')">today</button>
</div>
<div nz-col nzXs="6"  nzSm="6"  nzMd="6"  nzXl="5"  nzXXl="6">
    <fa-icon [icon]='icons.faArrowCircleRight' class="btn-next" (click)="calAction('next')"></fa-icon>
</div>
```

***list.component.ts***

```js
calAction(event: any) {
    let startDT: any;
    let endDT: any;
    switch (event) {
        case 'next':
            startDT = new Date(this.startDate);
            startDT.setDate(startDT.getDate() + 7);
            endDT = new Date(this.endDate);
            endDT.setDate(endDT.getDate() + 7);
            this.weekRange = format(startDT, 'DD') + " ~ " + format(endDT, 'DD');
            return false;
        case 'today':
            console.log('-today');
            break;
        case 'previous':
            startDT = new Date(this.startDate);
            startDT.setDate(startDT.getDate() - 7);
            endDT = new Date(this.endDate);
            endDT.setDate(endDT.getDate() - 7);
            this.weekRange = format(startDT, 'DD') + " ~ " + format(endDT, 'DD');
            break;
        default: break;
    }
}
```

Example when you click the next, it will only change once. When you click it again, it will not go to next week.

Comment: Your `this.startDate` and `this.endDate` doesn't change when you click so result of every click is the same

Answer (score 0):

It will always add 7 days to `this.startDate` and `this.endDate` value.

You need to setDate of `this.startDate` or `this.endDate`, not `startDT` and `endDT`, these two variables will always receive the same value since you are never updating based on weekRange value or the component variables

Comment: What is did is ```this.startDate.setDate(this.startDate.getDate() - 7);```
        ```this.endDate.setDate(this.endDate.getDate() - 7);```.